# BASIC HDD TO BOOTABLE HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, bootable-media, basic

My computer has 2 drives (attached image).

One drive is a SSD with 3 partitions:

At diskmanagement appears as a "basic disk".

In the first partition (A:), I have the "System Reserved". At diskmanagement appears as "Healthy (System, Active, Primary Partition)".

In the second partition (C:), I have the Windows 10 (last updated version). At diskmanagement appears as "Healthy (Boot, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)".

The third partition (D:), I use as personal storage. At diskmanagement appears as "Healthy (Primary Partition)".

The second drive is a HDD. Is physically placed in the DVD slot, so is a removable disk.

At diskmanagement appears as a "basic disk".

It has 6 partitions:

I don't have any other OS, just use the 6 partitions as personal storage.

The first 3 partitions (E:, F:, G:), appear at diskmanagement as "Healthy (Primary Partition)".

The last 3 partitions (H: I:, J:), appear at diskmanagement as "Healthy (Logical Drive)".

I want to install the "DLC Boot 2017 3.3 Build 170512" (http://dlcboot.com/), as a kind of bootable emergency/rescue disk.

But I don't want it in a USB external pendrive. And considering that my Windows 10 is in my SSD, then the logic is install "DLC" in my HDD.

Questions:

a) May I install "DLC" in my HDD ("basic" HDD)?

b) May I install "DLC" in my H:, I: or J: partitions (Logical Drives)?

c) Or I must install "DLC" in E:, F: or G: (Primary Partitions)?

d) How do I make any partition to be a bootable disk? How do I install "DLC" in any partition, to be bootable in my HDD?

e) Is it possible to do point "d", without deleting my 6 partitions?... without losing my 6 partitions and the content in each partition?

f) Considering that my HDD is a removable disk, "DLC" will work as a bootable disk in any other computer?

I will appreciate any help!

Thank you!

[Diskmanagement image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6jad.png)

Comment: Instead of painstakingly describing every last detail, you could’ve just provided a screenshot. ;) // Could you perhaps provide a link to this “DLC” stuff? Without knowing how exactly it works answering your question is not possible.

Comment: @DanielB http://dlcboot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED MY QUESTIONS:

My answers:

a) Yes.

b) No.

c) Yes. This was my key question!

d) Considering my question "C" as yes, is very easy to make any bootable of almost any software. By googling, there are lots of tutorials.

e) Yes.

f) Yes.